# Magento 2 : Call Static block wysiwyg images not using editor

Tags: magento2, static-block, cms-block, media, media-images

Any one have idea for how to `call images` in `Static block` not using editor like `{{media url="wysiwyg/demo.jpg"}}`?

Answer (score 1):

you can directly Upload image without using  the media{}

http://screencast.com/t/VdPLZPrqS

Or

By Code in phtml file use below :

```
        <img src="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'); ?>" alt="<?php echo __('Loading...') ?>">
```

Comment: i think its much faster to use directly upload . the image uploader at M2 is really slow for my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The solution without using the feature of the `wysiwyg` to upload images

Its really good for mass upload images.

First step: 
Upload the image fie to http://ROOT/pub/media/wysiwyg/demo.jpg

Second step :
Call it from the cms editor :

```
<img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/demo.jpg"}}" alt="your alt text here" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can upload the image in `skin/images` folder and call that path in static block like :

```
<img src="{{skin url='images/your image name'}}" />
```

Comment: i only tag "magento 2" but i forgot to put it inside the title... thanks